# TYPO3 Repository add new query

Tags: repository, typo3, extbase

I have a little problem.
How do I add the following to my repository?

[repository by pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/sm6E5PX4)

I would also like to add the following.

```
$date = new \DateTime('midnight');
$query->matching(
$query->greaterThanOrEqual('date', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
);
```

Separate from each other it works.
Thanks

Comment: What are you currently trying to achieve? All training records that are after the upcoming midnight?

Comment: In my repository, I'm going to give records by selected category. Now you want to see only records where the date is in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

```
...
$query->matching(
$query->logicalAnd(
$query -> logicalAnd($constraints),
$query->greaterThanOrEqual('date', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
)
);
...
```